# Finding integrating factor for a for some differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem :
Find the integration factor $\mu=\mu(x,y)$ for the PDE :
$$(2x^3y-y^2)dx - (2x^4 + xy)dy = 0 $$
I tried to solve it but I was unable to find the solution. If possible, I need a hint. Here is my step of solving it :
$$\mu (2x^3y-y^2)dx-\mu(2x^4 + xy)dy=0$$
$$\mu Pdx+\mu Qdy=0$$ where $P=2x^3y-y^2, -Q=2x^4 + xy$ .
By supposition that it is exact, then $$ \frac{\partial (\mu P)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (\mu Q)}{\partial x}$$
Hence $$(2x^3+y)x\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}+(2x^3-y)y\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=\mu(y-10x^3)
$$
. In order to find $\mu=\mu(x,y)$ i consider the associate ODE :
$$ \frac{dx}{(2x^3+y)x}=\frac{dy}{(2x^3-y)y}=\frac{d\mu}{(y-10x^3)}$$
Then I don't have an idea of solving it. Thanks

Comment: Just for a quick check, it is possible to express the DE in $u=(xy)$ and $v=\frac{x}{y}$ so that the remaining expression is separable.

Answer (score 3):

$$(2x^3y-y^2)dx+(-2x^4-xy)dy=0$$
In such kind of problems it can be useful to try $\mu(x,y)=x^\alpha y^\beta$, so
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[x^\alpha y^{\beta+1}(2x^3-y)\right]=
-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^{\alpha+1} y^\beta(2x^3+y)\right]$$
$$x^\alpha (\beta+1)y^\beta(2x^3-y)-x^\alpha y^{\beta + 1}=
-(\alpha+1)x^\alpha y^\beta(2x^3+y)-6x^{\alpha + 3}y^\beta$$
$$ (\beta+1)(2x^3-y)- y=
-(\alpha+1) (2x^3+y)-6x^{3}$$
$$(2\beta+2)x^3-(\beta+2)y=-(2\alpha+2)x^3-(\alpha+1)y-6x^3$$
$$2(\beta+\alpha +5)x^3-(\beta-\alpha+1)y=0$$
So:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\alpha+\beta=-5\\
&\alpha-\beta=1
\end{aligned}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\alpha=-2\\
&\beta=-3
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
As a result:
$$\mu(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2y^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

*An alternative solution.*

From the associated ODEs$^{(*)}$
$$
\frac{dx}{(2x^3+y)x}=\frac{dy}{(2x^3-y)y}=\frac{d\mu}{(y-10x^3)\color{red}{\mu}},
$$
it follows that
$$
\frac{\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}{y}}{(2x^3+y)+(2x^3-y)}=
\frac{\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{d\mu}{\mu}}{(2x^3-y)+(y-10x^3)}
$$
$$
\implies \frac{1}{4x^3}\left(\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}{y}\right)=
-\frac{1}{8x^3}\left(\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{d\mu}{\mu}\right)
$$
$$
\implies \frac{d\mu}{\mu}=-2\frac{dx}{x}-3\frac{dy}{y} 
\implies \ln|\mu|=-2\ln|x|-3\ln|y|+C
$$
$$
\implies \mu=\frac{c}{x^2y^3}. \quad{\square}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$ Notice the correction in the last term.